# VBA SaveAs crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `xlsm` file named `Summary.xlsm`. The Summary file gathers data from `xlsx` files in the same folder it's in. The folder the Summary file is in should only contain other Excel files named `IEM_######.xlsx` (IEM_ plus any six digit number), but sometimes the other Excel files are misnamed.

I've tried to create a macro that recognizes the falsely named files and renames them accordingly. The macro renames and saves the misnamed workbooks, but it always causes the so-called "white screen of death" and the Excel has to be closed. I've run the macro step-by-step and the SaveAS method seems to be the culprit.

Here's the offending code:

```
Sub Rename()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim FilesInPath As String, MyPath As String, MyFiles() As String, File As String, Number As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Wbk As Workbook

MyPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path + "\"

FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath)

FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox (FNum & " files were found.")

For i = 1 To FNum
    File = MyPath & MyFiles(i)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(File)
    Workbooks(MyFiles(i)).Activate
    If Not ((ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "IEM_######.xl*") Or (ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "Summary.xlsm")) Then
        Number = Worksheets("Time allocation").Range("B7")
        Name = "IEM_" & Number & ".xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs MyPath & Name
    End If
    Call Wbk.Close(True)
Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas what could be done?

Comment: Try changing `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` to `Wbk.SaveAs` - If that's not it, remove the `On Error Resume Next` so you can see the error name and number.

Comment: What is the value of Name when the code crashes? Are you sure that the Name is a valid file name?

Comment: @braX changing to Wbk.SaveAs has no effect - still keeps crashing. I tried removing the On Error Resume Next, but it doesn't show an error, it just crashes.

Comment: Put this right before the SaveAs line: `MsgBox MyPath & Name` - Are there any invalid characters in it?

Answer (score 0):

Could the culprit be in fact the `Call Wbk.Close` because it closes the `Summary.xlsm` as well (which contains the macro) and the "crash" is just in fact the macro closing the Summary Excel

^^This was the problem - macro works just fine now!